# RuntimeError: the derivative for ‘target’ is not implemented for Auto Encoder

Tags: pytorch

I am getting the following error - RuntimeError: the derivative for ‘target’ is not implemented
I did have a look at similar posts however they are different from my problem. I’m trying to code an Auto Encoder from scratch. Here’s my code -

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch import nn
from torchviz import make_dot

trainset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True)
data = trainset.data.float()
# print(trainset.data.shape)
# plt.imshow(trainset.data[9])
# plt.show()
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
data = data.to(device)
print(f"Using device = {device}")
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.encode = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(28*28, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 30),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.decode = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(30, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 28*28),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        encoded = self.encode(x)
        decoded = self.decode(encoded)
        return decoded

model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
# print(model)

lossFn  = nn.BCELoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-3)

for epoch in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(data)
    loss = lossFn(outputs, outputs)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    model.forward(data)
```

Comment: You are computing the loss by comparing the network output to itself: `lossFn(outputs, outputs)`. Is that intended? And is there a particular reason to run `model.forward(data)` after the optimizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having this error message is because you are calling a function which expects its argument to not require gradient computation. More specifically, `nn.BCELoss` expects the target (2nd argument) to not require gradient.

You can fix this by detaching the argument from the graph:

```
lossFn(outputs, outputs.detach())
```